# Call event from database on child click

Tags: c#

I have stored form name and events name in database, on form loading menu items and sub menus fetched from database, on child click I fetched event name from database and stored against variable, now I want call that event which is in that variable.

Check this:

```
// on form load
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        MnuStrip = new MenuStrip();
        base.Controls.Add(this.MnuStrip);
        MnuStrip.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(4, 71, 3);
        MnuStrip.ForeColor = Color.Orange;
        MnuStrip.Font = new Font("Arial", 12);

        string selectCommandText = "select Main_menu,Manu_Par_value,Status from MenuParent where Status='Y'";
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectCommandText, con);
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

        con.Open();

        adapter.Fill(dataTable);

        foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            this.MnuStripItem = new ToolStripMenuItem(row["Main_menu"].ToString());
            this.SubMenu(this.MnuStripItem, row["Manu_Par_value"].ToString());
            MnuStrip.Items.Add(this.MnuStripItem);
        }

        base.MainMenuStrip = MnuStrip;
        con.Close();
}

//submenu loads
public void SubMenu(ToolStripMenuItem mnu, string submenu)
{
        //SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT FRM_NAME FROM vw_pagerole WHERE MENUPARVAL='" + submenu + "' and status = 1 and UID = '" + Username + "' ", con);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select  mp.Main_menu, msm.Form_code, msm.form_Name, r.u_name from MenuParent mp ,MenuSubmenue msm, Rights r where mp.Manu_Par_value = msm.Manu_Par_value and mp.Manu_Par_value = r.Manu_Par_value and msm.menue_submenue_code  = r.menue_submenue_code and r.Rights_invisible = 1 and mp.Main_menu='" + mnu + "'  and r.u_name = '" + Username + "' ", con);
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dataTable);

        foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            ToolStripMenuItem item = new ToolStripMenuItem(row["form_Name"].ToString(), null, new EventHandler(ChildClick));
            mnu.DropDownItems.Add(item);
        }
}

//on child click
string eventclick;  //event name stored in this string
private void ChildClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       string query = ("select Form_code from MenuSubmenue where form_Name='" + sender.ToString() + "'");
       SqlCommand cmdd = new SqlCommand(query, con);    con.Open();

       var dbr = cmdd.ExecuteReader();

       while (dbr.Read())
       {
           eventclick = (string)dbr["Form_code"];
           label1.Text = eventclick;
       }
       con.Close();    
}
```

I want to call this event which is in the string type variable name eventclick

Answer (score 0):

You can use [reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection) to call method by name. 
Question does not specify neither class where method to be called is defined, nor signature (arguments) of this method. So I assume that method is defined as instance method of current Form and has signature `(object sender, EventArgs e)`, that is usual for event handlers. Following code then executes method with name defined in `eventclick` variable:

```
//Get instance method of this Form by method's name
var method = this.GetType().GetMethod(
    eventclick,
    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

// Prepare arguments for method to be called.
// Here I assume that method is standard event
// handler and has two arguments of type object
// and EventArgs
EventArgs eventArgs = null;//create new EventArgs() if required by called method
var arguments = new object[] { this, eventArgs };

//Invoke method with prepared arguments
method.Invoke(this, arguments);
```

Comment: dear I have a events like this,addprofiletoolstripmenuitem_click stored in database and I fetch into variable, now I want to call this event. I want to caste variable into event.  private void addProfileToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            profileform pf = new profileform
            {
                profiletype = 1,
                MdiParent = this
            };
            pf.Show();
        }

Comment: @MUHAMMADSOHAIL: My solution should work fine, then. But please note, that method names are case sensitive, so database must contain 'addProfileToolStripMenuItem_Click' instead of 'addprofiletoolstripmenuitem_click'.

Comment: yes it works thanks.but on some menues it gives an exception.A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.